# method modifiers with moose perl

Tags: perl, oop, attributes, filter, moose

I need to filter the "string" passed to the attribute "query"
and create a url with the filtered value.

my code

```
package Search;

use Any::Moose;

has query    => qw{ is ro isa Str required 1 };

# my method modifiers
around 'query' => sub {
    my $orig = shift;
    my $self = shift;

    my $content = $self->$orig(@_);

    # simple filter
    $content =~ s{[^\w\-\s]}{}gi;

    return $content;
};

sub create_uri {
    my $self = shift;
    my $uri = "http://localhost/search/".$self->{query};
    return $uri;
};
1;

package main;
my $obj = Search->new({
    query  => 'foo@#$%#%#@&-**bar@@#%!',
});

print $obj->query."\n";

print $obj->create_uri."\n"; # BAD
```

output here :

```
print $search->query;
```

> foo-bar , as expected.

When I call "create_uri"

```
print $search->create_uri;
```

output :

> http://localhost/search/foo@#$%#%#@&-**bar@@#%!

The "query" is completely dirty!
How to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `print $obj->query` you are calling the /subroutine/ called query, which calls your `around` sub. When you call `$self->{query}` from within `create_uri` you access the /attribute/ called query. There are two solutions:

1) Replace `$self->{query}` with `$self->query`

2) Instead of using `around query`, use the `trigger` option on the attribute, which calls a function every time the attribute is set. See http://metacpan.org/pod/Moose for information.

Comment: Thank you!
I used the first option.
but getting success using "tiggers" too.

Answer (score 2):

A couple more approaches for you to explore:

1. Use a `BUILDARGS` method in your class to clean up the query string before it gets assigned to the attribute at construction.

   ```
   sub BUILDARGS {
       my $type = shift;
       my $args = ref $_[0] eq 'HASH' ? shift : {@_};
       $args->{query} =~ s{[^\w\-\s]}{}gi;
       return $args;
   }
   ```
2. Use type coercion.

   ```
   subtype 'SafeStr', as 'Str', where {!/[^\w\-\s]/};

   coerce 'SafeStr', from 'Str', via {
       my $str = $_;
       $str =~ s/[^\w\-\s]//gi;
       return $str;
   };

   has 'query' => (
       is => 'ro',
       isa => 'SafeStr',
       required => 1,
       coerce => 1,
   );
   ```

Comment: Thank you! The two solutions work very well. 
I believe that using "coerce" will work best.   
I would have some gain by using "coerce" instead of "triggers" ?  
`has query   => qw{ is ro isa Str required 1 }, trigger => \&_filter_query;`